# NetLogo: Update globals per time step by selected patch value ?

Tags: netlogo

I have really simple question, which however I can't figure out.

I have some money to spend each year or `total_money_to_spend`. This sum will be renew next year. My turtle "buy" one patch with  per time step, thus my `total_money_to_spend` should decrease by `price` value and my 'cash_balance' should be `total_money_to_spend` - `price`. Turtle buys as many patches, as is allowed by `total_money_to_spend`. Thus:
`total_money_to_spend` = 50
`price` = 10
my 'cash_balance' should be 40, 30,20,10, 0...

As far, concept is super easy.

However, how to make it run in Netlogo? When I use `total_money_to_spend` as globals my 'cash_balance' doesn't update each tie step, it remains on 50. How can I update my 'cash_balance' as turtle is buying patches?

Thank you a lot !

```
globals [
  cash_balance        ; value total_money_to_spend - price of patch
  total_money_to_spend  ; sum of money
]

patches-own [
  price                 ; cost of the patch      
]

to setup
  ca
  set total_money_to_spend 50
  crt 1 [
    set color red ]
  ask patches [
    set price 10
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  if not any? patches with [price > 0] [
   stop ]
  spend-money
  tick
end

to spend-money            ; turtle goes shopping
  ask turtles [
    let price_of_patch [price] of patch-here
    move-to one-of patches with [price > 0]
    set pcolor magenta
    set price 0

   ; here is the problem - how to update my cash_balance??
; ------------------
    set cash_balance (total_money_to_spend - price_of_patch) 
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just figured it out: by updating `globals[]` within my procedure `spend-money`

```
to spend-money            ; turtle goes shopping

  set cash_balance (total_money_to_spend - 10) ; set the actual cash balance first
  ask turtles [        
    move-to one-of patches with [price > 0]
    set pcolor magenta
    set price 0
    set total_money_to_spend  (total_money_to_spend - 10) ; change the global variable within the procedure
  ]
end
```

But I'll appreciate any other possibilities ! ;) Thanks ! ;)

Comment: yes, this is the correct solution to updating. But you need to think about whether cash_balance and total_money_to_spend are actually global variables or turtles-own variables. You only have 1 turtle at the moment, so it doesn't matter. But if cash_balance is intended to be the amount that a particular turtle has available to spend, then it needs to be a turtles-own variable so that each turtle can have their own amount, rather than they all pull from some central store of money.

Comment: Good idea, thank you @JenB, I didn't even thought that I can set total_money various for my turtles...  but I will be really more interesting with you approach. Thanks !